# Magento Static Photo Url's and different size photos

Tags: image, magento, photo

I am trying to link to product photos on my magento installation and have a few questions.  What I would like to do is have a standardized url, where I provide the width and SKU and Magento generates the photo.

I believe this is built in to Magento, but can not find the documentation.  I want to be able to link to a photo like this (and use the magento cache as well).

http://mysite.com/media/photos/600x600/MYSKU.jpg

How can I tell magento to generate a 600x600 photo at a known url for a given product?  I am also using One Pica for CDN to S3/Cloudfront, but that portion shouldn't really be affected.

Answer (score 0):

Magento does have facilities for resizing images, but it typically does so as they are requested by other pages. The `catalog/image` helper, for instance, can help with this.

If you need to have arbitrary images output by the framework, you'll need to write a controller action for this to generate the newly resized images before returning them. Let me know if you need more detail on that front, but basically, you just need an action that parses the format request and creates the newly resized image on demand.

Your CDN wouldn't be affected in this case, though you could be clever about it and actually serve the assets from the CDN if you wanted to. In that case, you would generate the image, upload it to the CDN on the fly, and then return a 302 response for the resource.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe